# EasyMapping fails to map int from AFNetworking response

Tags: ios, json, mapping

Let me start by saying this if my fist time testing out EasyMapping and as such this is from a test project using the default Core Data constructors provided by Xcode when making a new Project.

When I try to map an initial login of a user I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute:property = "userID"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSArrayI; value = (
    12345
).'
```

The error is caused when trying to map the result of a POST using AFNetworking:

```
Successfully logged in with responseObject: {
    collection =     {
        items =         (
                        {
                accountid = 12345;
                fname = John;
                lname = Smith;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Using the following code:

```
// Login server call and resulting Mapping
[[MyHTTPSessionManager sharedManager] POST:@"users" parameters:parameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully logged in with responseObject: %@", responseObject);
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    // Start EasyMapping
    User *user = [EKManagedObjectMapper objectFromExternalRepresentation:responseObject withMapping:[User objectMapping] inManagedObjectContext:context];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
}];
```

User.m objectMapping fucntion

```
+ (EKManagedObjectMapping*)objectMapping
{
    return [EKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityName:@"User" withRootPath:@"collection.items" withBlock:^(EKManagedObjectMapping * _Nonnull mapping) {
        [mapping mapPropertiesFromDictionary:@{
                                           @"accountid" : @"userID",
                                           @"fname"     : @"firstName",
                                           @"lname"     : @"lastName",
                                           }];
        [mapping setPrimaryKey:@"userID"];
    }];
}
```

The Core data is setup such that it auto generates the following User+CoreDataProperties.h file:

```
#import "User.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface User (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *userID;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something basic here or not... I am using the following API versions as described in my Podfile:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1'
pod 'EasyMapping', '~> 0.18'
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything or if you have any questions on how I have things setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be around the nested JSON given by the server.

If I change the line to pass just the array held by the JSON object `items` the error seems be resolved.

```
User *user = [EKManagedObjectMapper objectFromExternalRepresentation:[[(NSDictionary*)responseObject objectForKey:@"collection"] objectForKey:@"items"] withMapping:[User objectMapping] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```